# is there a putty replacement that supports diverse colors? (over 4bit)

Tags: command-line, ssh, vim

putty seems to support only 3bit(8) colors while vim's default colorschemes seem to be 4bit colors. so with only 3bit colors it's sometimes even unreadable. is there any replacement that supports more colors? (I'm using windows 10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putty already supports 256 colors, and the next version (currently available as a development snapshot) supports true color which is 16.8 million colors.

Note that not many of the built-in vim color schemes support 256 colors.  Vim requires colors to be specified separately for true color (known as "gui mode" colors because these are used in gvim) and palette color (known as "terminal mode").  While many vim color schemes have true color support, their terminal mode colors only use the first 16 colors.  Because of this many vim color schemes will look bad over a terminal connection such as through putty because you only see those 16 colors (which is really just 8 colors, with 2 brightness levels).

But it is perfectly possible to create a vim color scheme that does support 256 colors properly and for that to work over putty right now, and that's what I do.

Comment: thank you so much I will look for more informations.